# Google Workspace email sending with Google Appscript is giving error. Message blocked Your message to has been blocked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

My script was working fine with normal Gmail account but is giving error with Google Workspace account.
I have read somewhere that I need to use GmailApp in place of MailApp, I have already done that. It seems that mail is sent but after that it is blocked.

I am getting the following error:

> Message blocked
>
> Your message to xxxxxxx has been blocked.
> See technical details below  for more information.
>
> LEARN MORE

The script is as below:

```
function exportPartAsPDF(selectedRanges,shId,regNo) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[shId];
var selectedRange = sheet.getRange(selectedRanges);
var pdfNameValue = sheet.getRange(regNo).getValue();
var pdfName = (pdfNameValue || "export") + ".pdf";
try {
    var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl(), sheet, selectedRange);
    blob.setName(pdfName);
    _sendMail(blob);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}

return;
}

function _getAsBlob(url, sheet, range) {
var rangeParam = "";
var sheetParam = "";
if (range) {
    rangeParam =
        "&r1=" +
        (range.getRow() - 1) +
        "&r2=" +
        range.getLastRow() +
        "&c1=" +
        (range.getColumn() - 1) +
        "&c2=" +
        range.getLastColumn();
}
if (sheet) {
    sheetParam = "&gid=" + sheet.getSheetId();
}
var exportUrl =
    url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, "") +
    "/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf" +
    "&size=A4" +                                //A3/A4/A5/B4/B5/letter/tabloid/legal/statement/executive/folio
    "&portrait=true" +
    '&scale=4' +
    "&fitw=true" +
    "&top_margin=0.5" +
    "&bottom_margin=0.5" +
    "&left_margin=0.5" +
    "&right_margin=0.5" +
    "&gridlines=false"  +              //true/false
    "&horizontal_alignment=CENTER" + //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    "&vertical_alignment=TOP" +      //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    "&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false" +
    "&pagenum=false" +
    "&gridlines=false" +
    "&fzr=FALSE" +
    sheetParam +
    rangeParam;
Logger.log("exportUrl=" + exportUrl);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    },
});

return response.getBlob();
}

function _sendMail(blob) {
var toEmail = "xxxxxx@gmail.com,xxxx@print.epsonconnect.com";
var htmlBody = "Payment Recieved";
var subject = "Reciept";

var options = {
    attachments: blob,
    htmlBody: htmlBody,
};
GmailApp.sendEmail(toEmail, subject, "html content only", options);
}
```

Comment: Since you have a workspace account have you tried to [Contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)?

Comment: yes, i tried. but they saythis.  Google Workspace Support, : Okay usually the Google Apps Script is not supported by us, since we do not have any visibility and tools to investigate the issues.

Comment: Is the same issue happening to other emails as well? Or is it exclusive with one user?